# writing to LMDB failed

Tags: c++, database, caffe, lmdb

I was trying write data to lmdb database (took reference from caffe/tools/convert_imageset.cpp). There were no errors in console but the file size of .mdb file remains zero i.e no data is written to the file but data and lock file are created.
The part of the code that I tried is  :

```
scoped_ptr<db::DB> db(db::GetDB("lmdb"));
db->Open(argv[3], db::NEW);
scoped_ptr<db::Transaction> txn(db->NewTransaction());

datum.SerializeToString(&out);
txn->Put(key1, out);
txn->Commit();
```

I was not able to figure out if I am missing something. Any references to how LMBD works would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean as *size of .lmdb*? As I know, lmdb database from **caffe** is a folder with `data.mdb` and `lock.mdb`. If you see these 2 files with non-zero size, everything is OK.

Comment: Sorry for being confusing, I mean the size of the data.mdb file is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the key is not empty before calling `Put`.
You could use `mdb_dump` and print the contents of the database.

Comment: can you please provide a more detailed example on how to use `mdb_dump`?

Comment: `mdb_dump -pa <dbpathname>` will print the contents of all database within the environment. The keys and values will be printed in ascii.